# Term for past, present, and future classification of nouns

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, time

In a software program, I assign contracts a temporal classification as a past, current, or future agreement.  I need a descriptive term for this classification and "temporal classification" seems awkward.  I considered "age," but that word has too many duration-related connotations.  I have thought about calling this classification the agreement's "era."

In grammar, "tense" is a verb's temporal classification.  Is there an appropriate word to use in describing a noun's temporal status or classification as past, present, or future?

Comment: Your "contract" ***was, is,*** or ***will*** still be a contract, regardless of the temporal frame, so I don't think it makes sense to ask for an appropriate word to use in describing a *noun's* temporal status. Nouns simply don't have temporal aspects. I think you should just label your column **Status** (to contain values such as **expired, active, prospective** or similar).

Comment: Well, we do describe nouns temporally using adjectives such as "old" and "new."  I am just asking of there is a term for that type of description.  I agree that "status" might apply, but that is a very overloaded term which is used elsewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**[Stative](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stative)**

> expressing a state or condition, usually used in simple tenses.

I imagine you can describe the temporal designation as the contract's **stative**. You could have a column marked **stative** with 3 boxes (past, present, future).

Answer (score 0):

Though it may not be the best option generally, for a software program that I am working on now, I ended up using "period" for a type which could represent past, present or future at any given instance. Just in case someone else ends up here looking for the same...